# How to specify an alternate image in CSS background-image property if WebP format is not supported by browser

Tags: html, css, performance, webp

I have an a element with background image

```
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4"><a class="thumbnail" href="~/home/products"
              style="background-image: url(/../images/image-370x370.jpg)">
                  <div class="thumbnail-caption">
                    <h3 class="thumbnail-heading">E-Commerce</h3>
                    <div class="thumbnail-inner">
                      <div class="thumbnail-content">
                        this is a complete e-commerce solution through which you can manage your online store.
                      </div>
                      <div class="thumbnail-icon fa-angle-right"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div></a>
        </div>
```

In the second line
`style="background-image: url(/../images/image-370x370.jpg)"`
I want to use the WebP format image with css background-image to reduce the size of request and specify the alternate image if WebP is not supported.

As we can do this with picture element:

```
<picture>
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="flower.webp">
  <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="flower.jpg">
  <img src="flower.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using << background-image: "image-set" >> like:

```
style='background-image: url("/../images/image-370x370.jpg");
       background-image: image-set("/../images/image-370x370.webp", "/../images/image-370x370.jpg");
       background-image: -webkit-image-set("/../images/image-370x370.webp", "/../images/image-370x370.jpg");'
```

That worked for me.

Comment: MDM has a nice article with examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image/image-set#using_image-set_to_provide_alternative_image_formats

Answer (score -1):

You can use multiple images:

```
style="background-image: url(/../images/image-370x370.webp),
                         url(/../images/image-370x370.jpg)"
```

Comment: From MDN: The background images are drawn on stacking context layers on top of each other. The first layer specified is drawn as if it is closest to the user. so the above will not fulfil the desired purpose

Comment: if webp is supported this would load both the webp version as well as the other file (jpg version) too